# What is the ampersand-equals operator used for in Java?

Tags: java, operators, code-analysis

Does Java have an `&=` operator? I'm seeing this code:

```
boolean allReady = true;            
for(Entry<String,Boolean> ace : factory.readyAces.entrySet()) {
    allReady &= ace.getValue();
```

What is `&=`?

Comment: Here is the [documentation][1] we are not here to feed answers.


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Lol "too localized"? Wish there was shortcut `&&=`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
allReady = allReady & ace.getValue();
```

This is a bit-wise and.  It means you always evaluate both sides, then take the "logical and" (result is only true if both sides are true).

Answer (score 4):

this is a shortcut for the bit-wise anding

```
allReady = allReady & ace.getValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a Bitwise AND assignment operator. The equivalent of doing:

```
allReady = allReady & ace.getValue();
```